# How can I do something after the next pagebreak?

Tags: counters, page-breaking

I'm writing a document where I say something like "if you look at Figure 1 on the next page, then you will see that blah blah blah". So what I want to do is have latex skip a number when numbering pages. I know that I can do this using

```
\addtocounter{page}{1}
```

but, that will increase the counter on whatever page that command appears on. So I could compile my document and put it somewhere within the next page, but then if something changes and stuff moves around, it could end up on the wrong page, sort-of defeating the whole purpose of latex!

So is there some way to tell latex to count up a page number AFTER the next pagebreak, wherever that pagebreak might be? ps I'm doing this so I can staple in a handwritten page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible by loading the afterpage package and then writing at the necessary point

```
\afterpage{\stepcounter{page}}
```

although personally I'd probably do

```
\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}
```

and then throw away the extra page. (Might depend, really.)

Comment: Ah thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!